# track airline miles in single location

Tags: online-resources, airlines, loyalty-programs

Myself and my family travel domestic or international not more than twice a year. We have raked up many thousands of miles across many different airlines. However we have never been able to use any miles to buy next flights or even buy any thing from airline store using miles.

The problem lies in the fact that we use the cheapest (and other factors like less stops) airline available for the trip. First problem is that it is difficult to claim miles because I usually do not have miles membership number handy while booking tickets and usually miss claiming miles after trip is done. Second problem is that because miles are spread across different airlines it is difficult to track and use them while booking new travel.

Is there a good service which works on all airlines (e.g even those that are not part of any alliances like emirates). I want a single location to track my miles and have handy access to my membership numbers and redeem tickets or material goods using miles.

Answer (score 1):

For tracking your points, the service you're looking for is [AwardWallet](https://awardwallet.com/) (no endorsement). It's apparently the only service that is able to display the point balance of various difference awards accounts automatically. Notably, it doesn't support a few major services, like United MileagePlus, but it does support Emirates, and it's the closest I think you'll get.

As far as remembering loyalty numbers, I would recommend to first of all using a password manager like [1Password](https://1password.com/). 1Password can easily store such things and recall them in your browser using a browser extension. Plus it's a great habit for passwords as well.

Comment: I could see it being useful, especially if combined with a flight search engine that displayed prices in miles.  You could see whether you had enough miles for flights to various destinations on various airlines, and compare your options.  It could also help you keep track of expiration dates.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's fair. I took the implication from the rest of the question was that they had all of their miles spread across all of the airlines so they didn't have enough to redeem on any individual airline, so they were looking for a hub that they could exchange them between and then be able to redeem for something. Looks like their talking more about AwardWallet then. I will amend

Comment: TripIt Pro has this feature too, not endorsing tripit however cause their support is the worst I have ever encountered